# Are the bias terms added by default on each layer in tensorflow models?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, bias-neuron

Are the bias terms added by default when creating the tensorflow neural network models?

To rephrase, if x is the input to a particular layer, y is the ouput, W is the weight matrix and b is the bias , then the output of the layer is given by,

```
  y = W^t x + b
```

So is the bias added by default when we create the model ?

Comment: there are many layers. Which layer are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about  convolutional layers in the slim library. My layer looks like this: net = slim.conv2d(net,number_filters,[size_filters,size_filters],stride = stride,scope=scope,padding=padding) .Is the bias already added in the output of this layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your own model from scratch, you have to create your own trainable variables for the weights and biases explicitly. Tensorflow does not create them by default.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n))

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m], stddev=0.01))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([m]))

y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
```

Comment: I am creating a CNN using the slim library from tensorflow. My first convolutional layer looks like this:

       net = slim.conv2d(input,number_filters,[size_filters,size_filters],
        stride=stride,scope=scope,padding=padding)
        
This layer is followed my multiple conv2d layers with max pooling layers as well. I want to know if the biases are already added in the output of this layer. Sorry if the question was not clear initially.

Comment: In that case, I see that slim does help to simplify the operation. Based on their explanation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim#layers). So slim.conv2d already helps you with the creation of the weights and biases

Answer (score 0):

No, You need to define biases and all the variable by yourself. If you not defined biases then your model will be

```
y = w^tx
```

Comment: What if I am using pre-defined layers in from the slim library something like this: et = slim.conv2d(input,number_filters,[size_filters,size_filters]‌​, stride=stride,scope=scope,padding=padding). I am creating a CNN with conv2d and max pooling layers from the slim library in tensorflow. Is the bias already added in the output of this layer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear which case did you refer in the three possibilities(at least) bellow:

1. suppose the layer is a basic rnn layer(though you provided only one input and one output), then the answer is yes. Check out this [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L258). The third parameter of the linear function is true, indicating the bias is added in default.
2. suppose that you did a linear projection, then you can custom it yourself. A bias can be omitted, for example in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L579).
3. and using this [API: tf.nn.xw_plus_b](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/xw_plus_b), you can define your own bias.

Comment: I am creating a CNN using the slim library. I have multiple conv2d layers and the maxpooling layers in my network. I want to know if the bias is already added in the output of the CNN layers.

Comment: I am not sure about slim library. But I guess internally biases are there as I have seen in tensor flow case when we define RNN layer weight and biases are internally created.

Comment: Ja, das denke ich auch.